# How to get a callback on webrtc screen share end button click?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Can we get a callback on "Stop Sharing" button? I am trying to do it the other way by

```
  stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = function () {
    // doWhatYouNeedToDo();
  };
```

I am getting the event over here only if the shared screen is in foreground. Whenever I put the shared screen in background I am not getting the event.

Comment: I have one more finding - As soon as we click "stop sharing" the 

'stream.getVideoTracks()[0].readyState'   changes from "live" to "ended"

Currently I am trying to complete my stuff behind this thing.

Comment: how about using, `stream.onended` or `stream.oninactive`?

Comment: `stream.onended` too was not getting triggered everytime. I just looped over and polled for readyState and got the thing.

Comment: what browser, I just checked in chrome, it works fine...

Comment: it's chromium on ubuntu 14.

Comment: sorry, don't have chromium set-up, but in windows it works fine, also are you using some framework in between like angular?

Comment: Yeah. I am using angular.

Comment: that might be the cause of the problem, bec this is async, outside the angular loop, you might need to do something like `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: I don't think so. `$scope.$apply()` comes into the picture when you wanna reflect something on UI via angularjs context. But I was having a `console.log('screen ended')` That too was not getting invoked in `stream.onended` callback.

Comment: I read somewhere that `ended` attribute is deprecated, give `stream.oninactive` a try...

Comment: just had a try with `stream.oninactive`. Not getting callback at all in this one

`stream.oninactive = function(){
              console.log('on inactive invoked');
            }`